# Encountering errors of obtaining dependencies when starting grails application

Tags: web, grails, dependencies

I'm new to Grails web framework. I got this error when running my first grails app from the terminal. Below is the error I got.

```
> | Downloading:
> org/apache/commons/commons-parent/17/commons-parent-17.pom | Error
> Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact
> descriptor  for org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3 (Use --stacktrace
> to see the full trace)
> 
> | Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is
> normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured
> proxy) or missing repos itories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.
> Please verify your configuration to continue.
```

I'm running this app with the internet connection but this error still occurs. How can I fix this error?

Comment: You mentioned below that you are using the command line. Are you doing this at work or home? Are you behind a firewall and have you configured your proxy in the conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are u sure you are using a the correct download for grails, it seems that your trying to connect to the internet and your grails can't ? may be check your proxy settings? or what you are really trying to do in the command line ?

Comment: just i try my first app in command line.I download grails-2.3.1 from the site.

Answer (score 1):

Your console log says, you can not connect to internet for downloading dependencies.
But its not the case. Maven has stopped http repositories and that is the root cause.
You have to use https. If you could not connect to https for some reason, here is workaround to that:

```
mavenRepo "http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
```

Putting above line in BuildConfig.groovy will resolve your issue and start downloading dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What mavenRepo's do you have in your BuildConfig.groovy. I found that I had to add a few, here's mine:

```
  repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
}
```

Comment: do you have the same mavenRepo's as i have?

Comment: yap but these lines are commented                                   mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

> grails refresh-dependencies

before you try to run your app?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Grails, SO and JDK do you have?, in Windows 8 with JDK Java SE 7u45 and Grails 2.3.1 i have a lot of problems; I had to make a downgrade to JDK

Comment: Grails 2.3.1, yes I'm also thinking's that is problem in the version but 2.2.4 working fine